# How to get closed issues for current sprint youtrack rest api?

Tags: javascript, youtrack, youtrack-api

Help make a request to get a list of closed tasks for the current sprint.

For open such a request turned out

base_url/api/issues?query=%23resolved%20%23я&fields=summary,idReadable,customFields(name,value(name))&customFields=Оценка&customFields

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get resolved tasks in the current sprint of the `boardname` board, please use the following endpoint: `/api/issues?query=%23resolved%20Board%20boardname:%20%7BCurrent%20sprint%7D%20&fields=summary,idReadable,customFields(name,value(name))`. Edit the fields part as necessary.